# Accessing Arrays in Array in PHP Views

Tags: php, codeigniter, view

This is an additional question from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084098/how-to-pass-a-multi-dimensional-array-to-a-view-in-codeigniter).

I have this array containing multiple values as well as arrays. I know that I can use

```
$data['property'] = value;
```

And since I'm in the view after sending the $data to it, I know I can

```
echo $PROPERTY;
```

However, this array also contains arrays.

```
[0] => Array ( [CSS] => css/style_centre_paiement_paiements_1.css [PAGE_NAME] =>
ACCUEIL [RANK] => PARENT [THREAD] => Accueil [FULL_NAME] => Marc Bélanger [C1] => Accueil
[C2] => Inscription - Enfant
[C3] => Centre de Paiement
[C4] =>Nous contacter
[C5] =>Votre compte
[C6] => 
[C7] =>Déconnexion
)[1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [TITRE]...
```

The [1] contains an array of several [TITRE],[MESSAGE][DATE] sets. Right now, by sending this total array to the view, I can echo things like $THREAD and get the correct value. But how should I proceed to access the value of each of my sets ? Since the array of sets is in [1], then [0], I don't really know how to do it. And I don't want to to echo [TITRE] because there is more than one [TITRE] and I want to show them all, not just one. What I would like would be to do something like this :

```
foreach ($alert as $row)
    {
      ....
    }
```

Any clue how to help ?

Comment: Hint: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php Test if a var is an array or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure what you mean, but if you want to do a foreach() with an array you could try

```
foreach ($array as $array => $subarray)
{
//code
}
```